# Make a div size responsive with a set height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a background image wrapped in a div and inside is a responsive background image so it scales according to the screen size. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the div wrapper responsive while setting it's max height limit to 350px. Here's what I have:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 divWrapper">
   <div class="backgroundImage" style="backgroundImgUrl">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

.divWrapper {
   max-height: 350px;
   height: 350px;
 } 


.backgroundImage {
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Every time I scale the screen down, the image resizes and the div wrapper stays the saame and vice versa

Comment: Remove height property

Comment: It might be helpful to see your HMTL markup as well as the CSS. Are there other relevant styles you are not showing us? What gives `.backgroundImage` its height?

Comment: added my HTML markup @JonathanNicol

Comment: And its height? A div by itself has no height, and it won't stretch to fill its container, so presumably you are setting its height somewhere? Or is that what you're trying to figure out - how to make it as tall as its container?

Comment: I never set the height of the div @JonathanNicol I relied on the height of my background image

Comment: Let me demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/5axL1tsc/ That is your markup and styles, with a border added around the relevant divs so we can see them. The div with the red corder contains a background image. Notice how it has no height?

Comment: it's max height is suppose to be 350px. I made the changes

Comment: Note that a background image does _not_ give it's element height.  So, `div.backgroundImage` height is irrespective of background image, but rather by either CSS height *or* by the contents of the `div` element (again, not including background image)

Comment: @AlfieMcNarutoad Thanks for making that change, the question makes more sense to me now. I have added an answer showing how to have the background image fill its container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set your Div with background-size:cover;

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
.backgroundImage {
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

to:

```
.backgroundImage {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ujjn5cvt/